# R : warning : Coercing data.frame to matrix via factor level numberings

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I read some data frames from CSV files using the read.table function. 
I gave the read.table function the

```
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
```

argument.

I also set the row names of each data frame to : `rownames(A) <- seq(1: nrow(A)).`

I merged these data frames using a sequence of cbinds.

```
C = cbind(A,B)
E = cbind(C,D)
F = cbind(C,E)
```

I created a big matrix ( bigmemory package ) using:

```
result <- as.big.matrix ( F , type="double", backingfile = "final.bin", 
backingpath = getwd(), descriptorfile = "final.desc")
```

This actually worked well but it gave me the following warning message:

> **Coercing data.frame to matrix via factor level numberings**

Why did it give me this warning message? When I read in the data frames, I put in `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` so why the factors?

Comment: Are all the columns in your original data strings, or are some strings and some numbers?

Comment: I'd suggest trying to create a small reproducible example. If the process of putting that together doesn't solve the problem for you, you can post it here and will probably get better feedback. Cheers.